# sqlalchemy before_flush event handler doesn't see change of foreign key when instance is assigned to relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `before_flush` event listener which checks if the employee's manager changed. In such case a record is automatically created in `EmpManHist` table. `manager` is self-reference to the `Employee` table.
Here's my table definition:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    emp_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    manager_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('employees.emp_id'))
    direct_reports = relationship('Employee', backref=backref('manager', remote_side=[emp_id]))
```

When I assign new manager to an employee by modifying the ForeignKey (`manager_id`) directly it is correctly picked up by the event listener. But when I do an instance assignment it doesn't:

```
# this code does not pick up the manager_id change in the 'before_flush' event listener
emp2.manager = emp3
dal.session.add(emp2)
dal.session.commit()

# this does
emp2.manager_id = '1'
dal.session.add(emp2)
dal.session.commit()
```

Why is that?
I'm using python 3.6.3 and sqlalchemy 1.1.13

Below is the full working example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import get_history
import datetime


Base = declarative_base()


class DataAccessLayer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn_string = conn_string
        self.engine = None
        self.session = None
        self.Session = None
        self.echo = True

    def connect(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(self.conn_string, echo=self.echo)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    emp_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    manager_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('employees.emp_id'))
    direct_reports = relationship('Employee', backref=backref('manager', remote_side=[emp_id]))


class EmpManHist(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'emp_man_history'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    emp_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('employees.emp_id'))
    man_id_from = Column(String, ForeignKey('employees.emp_id'))
    man_id_to = Column(String, ForeignKey('employees.emp_id'))
    when = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)

    manager_from = relationship('Employee', foreign_keys=[man_id_from])
    manager_to = relationship('Employee', foreign_keys=[man_id_to])


conn_string = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
dal = DataAccessLayer()
dal.echo = True
dal.connect()
dal.session = dal.Session()


@event.listens_for(dal.session, 'before_flush')
def _emp_history_update(session, flush_context, instances):
    print("BEFORE FLUSH")
    for instance in session.dirty:
        if not isinstance(instance, Employee):
            continue
        man_hist = get_history(instance, 'manager_id')
        if man_hist.added:
            if man_hist.deleted:
                man_deleted = str(man_hist.deleted[0])
            else:
                man_deleted = None
            emp_man_hist = EmpManHist(emp_id=instance.emp_id, man_id_from=man_deleted,
                                      man_id_to=str(man_hist.added[0]))
            session.add(emp_man_hist)


emp1 = Employee(emp_id='1', name="AAA")
emp2 = Employee(emp_id='2', name="BBB", manager_id='1')
emp3 = Employee(emp_id='3', name="CCC", manager_id='1')


dal.session.add(emp3)
dal.session.flush()
dal.session.add(emp1)
dal.session.add(emp2)

dal.session.commit()

# this code does not pick up the manager_id change in the 'before_flush' event listener
emp2.manager = emp3
dal.session.add(emp2)
dal.session.add(emp3)
dal.session.commit()

# this does
emp2.manager_id = '1'
dal.session.add(emp2)
dal.session.commit()
```

Comment: +1 for example that includes creating the test data but I get an `IntegrityError` at the first `dal.session.flush()` as `emp1` doesn't exist yet and so the foreign key constraint fails.

Comment: Also, in the section under `# this does` you assign `emp2.manager_id = '1'` but I assume that should be ` = '3'` in keeping with the example above it that doesn't work?

Comment: I wanted to provide a full working example that you would run as a whole thing. I first change `emp2` manager to `emp3` by instance assignment and commit to show that the `before_flush` event listener did not pick up the id change. But it did happen after the flush. So in the `# this does` section I change it back to `emp1`. Also I just double checked and running the whole code does not produce `IntegrityError`. Could it be we're using different SQLAlchemy versions? Mine is 1.1.13.

Comment: Oh cool, I understand why you set it to 1, I was looking at them as two separate examples. As for the `IntegrityError`, Foreign Keys are not enforced by default in `SQLite3`, I was running on `MySQL`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLAlchemy does not immediately update Foreign Key fields when relationship attributes are changed. So the answer to your question is that the `before_flush` event is triggered before SQLAlchemy updates the Foreign Key value of the `Employee` instance as part of the `flush` operation.

In the case where you specifically update the `manager_id` attribute yourself, the attribute is altered prior to the `before_flush` event being triggered which is why you see the change in your `_emp_history_update` function in that case.

You can still do everything that you want using the `after_flush` event as `session.dirty` hasn't been cleared out by that point. So I changed your event listener to this:

```
@event.listens_for(session, 'after_flush')
def _emp_history_update(session, flush_context):
    for instance in session.dirty:
        if not isinstance(instance, Employee):
            continue
        man_hist = get_history(instance, 'manager_id')
        if man_hist.added:
            if man_hist.deleted:
                man_deleted = str(man_hist.deleted[0])
            else:
                man_deleted = None
            emp_man_hist = EmpManHist(emp_id=instance.emp_id, man_id_from=man_deleted,
                                      man_id_to=str(man_hist.added[0]))
            session.add(emp_man_hist)
```

And this was the test code:

```
emp1 = Employee(emp_id='1', name="AAA")
emp2 = Employee(emp_id='2', name="BBB", manager_id='1')
emp3 = Employee(emp_id='3', name="CCC", manager_id='1')

# I'm not using your DataAccessLayer object but that doesn't change anything
session.add_all([emp1, emp2, emp3])
# i've not explicitly called session.flush() as it's called by session.commit() anyway
session.commit()

# change the emp2's manager through relationship attribute
emp2.manager = emp3
# no need to re-add the Employee objects to the session
session.commit()

for change in session.query(EmpManHist).all():
    print(f'Employee {change.emp_id} changed to mgr_id {change.man_id_to}')
```

Which outputs:

```
Employee 2 changed to mgr_id 3
```

One more thing that I've noticed is that in this section of your event listener:

```
    if man_hist.added:
        if man_hist.deleted:
            man_deleted = str(man_hist.deleted[0])
        else:
            man_deleted = None
        emp_man_hist = EmpManHist(emp_id=instance.emp_id, man_id_from=man_deleted,
                                  man_id_to=str(man_hist.added[0]))
        session.add(emp_man_hist)
```

Changing the `manager_id` of an `Employee` instance either through directly changing the attribute yourself, or by changing the `Employee.manager` relationship attribute, never makes an instance show in `man_hist.deleted`. Due to that, your `man_id_from` attribute of `EmpManHist` instances is always `None`.

This is the log of the `INSERT` into the `emp_man_hist` which is generated from your example code and you can see from the list of values in the second line that the second value, which aligns with `man_id_from` is being asigned `None`:

```
2018-07-27 09:03:41,189 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO emp_man_history (emp_id, man_id_from, man_id_to, "when") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-07-27 09:03:41,189 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('2', None, '1', '2018-07-27 09:03:41.188906')
```

Comment: That's weird... I extracted this example from a much bigger project and didn't notice that `man_hist.deleted` is always `None` here. In my project it works fine, meaning when manager change is picked up by event listener it also detects the old value. I can't see the why it doesn't work here. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. I've added the logs generated from running your example above with no modification.